# What is the CSS that makes font-awesome's stack icons work?

Tags: css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

Can someone explain the css behind font awesome's stack icon?  I'm trying to create my own custom stack icon font, but I fail to get them to stack the way font-awesome manage to do it.

I'm not sure WHICH is the specific css that they manage to make the stack "happen".

(As far as I know, this is not a duplicate: There are a lot of questions about how to USE the font-awesome stack icons, but none behind the mechanism of it.)

Comment: Right-click, 'inspect element' and you can see exactly which styles are applied.

Comment: I can see the style exactly, but I'd like to understand it.  For example, why do they need to add 2em to the stack class?  I understand that they use relative positioning for the stack class, and absolute for the stacking icons, but how do they make them line up the way they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons themselves are contained in the FontAwesome font. The magic is in the number of helper CSS classes that let you select an icon character and let you position these icons easily. Each class is reponsible for a piece of functionality, so together they give you a modular build-up of an icon.

*Stacking* 
When stacking two icons with FontAwesome, you need an extra span with the class `fa-stack`. This span adds position: relative, which allows you to position the two stacked icons absolutely and by doing so, making them overlap.

The size is also set to 2em, because the background (or overlay) is twice the size compared to a normal icon. Givin it this exact width makes sure that enough space is claimed for the icons, but also that the smaller icon can be properly centered horizontally.

The icons inside the span get a class like `fa-stack-1x` or `fa-stack-2x` that dictates their size and position within the parent span.

So, summing up the most notable classes (for icons and stacking):

- `fa` set the right font. This basically makes an icon out of an element.
- `fa-twitter`, and many others let you select a character. This character is added in the CSS in the `content` of the `::before` pseudo-element.
- `fa-stack` defines a container to contain the stacked icons. Adds `position: relative`, so you can absolutely position icons in it.
- `fa-stack-2x` makes the icon twice the size and positions it at 0,0 in the parent container. Used for background or overlay icons.
- `fa-stack-1x` uses 100% of the width of the parent and centers the icon in it. Used for the smaller image icon that is used with the background/overlay icon.

Other features, like rotation, work in a similar way by just adding the right class.

Comment: Ahh.  I see why I'm having problems.  I already have positioning to some of my icons.  So the absolute override them and they don't layer the way I expect them to.

Comment: I"m also having trouble making the one I want to stack on top to be the top layer.  I added z-index to individual icon I want to go on top of the one at the bottom (with lower z-index), but it doesn't seem to work.  I switch the order of the div inside <fa-stack>, it didn't do anything.  I wish I can put a fiddle, but it requires me to upload my icons somewhere...?

Comment: If you don't add z-index at all, you can let the order of the elements in the DOM determine which one is on top. Check the [examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) and see that the `no camera` icon has an overlay, while `flag on circle` has a background. The only difference is the order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it to you with the CDN file provided by font-awesome:
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Let's take a look at this html:

The css that makes this piece of html render an icon is the following:

```
.fa {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

This declaration tells to the class FA to use the font-awesome font.

Then, for any fa-whateverIconName you add, you'll have the following:

```
.fa-connectdevelop:before {
    content: "\f20e"
}
```

So basically, when you use font-awesome's given classes, your html item gets the proper font and a before pseudo-element with your class's corresponding icon.